# testing for Intersecting a poly line and MKMapItem

Tags: swiftui, mapkit, mkpolyline, poly, cgrectintersectsrect

I'm trying to draw a route using MapKit and SwiftUI and then have a MapItem aka (Marker) that I can see is intersecting with the route.

I tried using creating an MKCircle for my MapPoint that I want to avoid and then tested the boundingMapRect of the MKCircle testing against the boundingMapRect of the route's polyline. The issue that I am having is that the polyline of the route is creating a MapRect that is the size of my visible map and therefore it's always showing an intersecting point.

Below is my sample code

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedResult: MKMapItem?
    @State private var route: [MKRoute]?
    @State var intersection: Bool = false
    
    private let startingPoint = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
        latitude: 40.83657722488077,
        longitude: 14.306896671048852
    )
    
    private let destinationCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
        latitude: 40.849761,
        longitude: 14.263364
    )
    
    private let testPoint = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
        latitude: 40.84013,
        longitude: 14.29389
    )
    
    var locations = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()
    
    var body: some View {
        Map(selection: $selectedResult) {
            // Adding the marker for the starting point
            Marker("Start", coordinate: self.startingPoint)
                .tint(.green)
            Marker("End", coordinate: destinationCoordinates)
                .tint(.green)
            Marker("Low Bridge", systemImage: "x.circle.fill", coordinate: testPoint)
//           Show the route if it is available
            MapCircle(center: testPoint, radius: 0.01)
                    .foregroundStyle(.cyan.opacity(0.5))
                    .mapOverlayLevel(level: .aboveRoads)
            
            if (route?.count ?? 0 > 0) {
                ForEach (route!, id: \.self) { r in
                    MapPolyline(r)
                    .stroke(.blue, lineWidth: 5)
                }
            }
            
            
        }
        .onChange(of: intersection) {
            print(intersection)
        }
        .onChange(of: selectedResult){
            getDirections()
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.selectedResult = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: self.destinationCoordinates))
        }
    }
    
    func getDirections() {
        self.route = []
        
        // Check if there is a selected result
        guard let selectedResult else { return }
        
        // Create and configure the request
        let request = MKDirections.Request()
        request.source = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: self.startingPoint))
        request.destination = self.selectedResult
        request.transportType = .walking
        request.requestsAlternateRoutes = false
        
        // Get the directions based on the request
        Task {
            let directions = MKDirections(request: request)
            let response = try? await directions.calculate()
            route = response?.routes
            if (route?.count ?? 0 > 0) {
                route?.forEach() { r in
                    print(r.name)
                    let lb = MKCircle(center: testPoint, radius: 0.0001)
                    
                    if (lb.boundingMapRect.intersects(r.polyline.boundingMapRect))==true {
                        print(lb.boundingMapRect)
                        print(r.polyline.boundingMapRect)
                        print("Intersect")
                    } else {
                        print("Clear")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```